# Monopoly Deal: Fairest way of removing extra cards

Tags: monopoly-deal

It is not explicitly specified how the remaining card(s) should be removed before finishing your turn.
The obvious option is to put it at the bottom of the deck, but in this way a player can manipulate the odds (for instance, if a player needs a red property to win then he can throw to the bottom of the deck a property of that color).

So, is there a better option than putting the remaining cards at the bottom of the deck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options:

1. The rules as written say that they should go on the bottom of the deck.
2. You could opt to have players put extra cards face up in the public discard instead.

The official rulebook says the following (my emphasis):

> If you have more than 7 cards in your hand at the end of your turn (not including cards on the table) **discard extras to the bottom of the draw pile** so you only have 7.

This is an unusual way for games to handle discards; I think that this is an inelegant solution, and it sounds like you do too.  [monopolydealrules.com](http://monopolydealrules.com) is non-authoritative collection of rules clarifications and improvements sourced from the community, and suggests a discarding face-up to the discard pile.  Their "general rules" say:

> At the end of a turn, a player cannot have more than 7 cards in their hand. If they do, they need to discard the excess cards into the discard pile in the middle.

This is only a meaningful difference if you actually go through the entire deck in the game, which is unlikely.  I'd recommend going with having discards go to the discard pile, as it's a more normal way to handle discards and it addresses the concern of players potentially manipulating the deck through discards.

Comment: So, should  the remaining players see them?

Comment: @David The discard is public; all players will see them

Comment: You say the rulebook at MDR says..., but the rulebook there ("Instruction Book") says to put them under the draw pile. It's the "general rules" section there that changes it to "put them in the discard pile".

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson The rulebook is the section "General Rules"

Comment: Ah. That doesn't match the usual usage of "rulebook", but OK.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I've edited it for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which version you have. Some say to place the cards under the draw pile while others say to place it on the play pile (which is sometimes called the discard pile)

#### One Way (under the draw pile)

If placing them under the draw pile, the rules don't specify the order when placing them on the bottom of the draw pile, so you're free to choose whatever order you like.

[Rules](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/monopoly/deal-game-rules.php):

> 3. End your Turn
>    If you have more than 7 cards in your hand at the end of your turn (not including cards on the table) discard extras to the bottom of the draw pile so you only have 7.

It's worded differently in [these rules](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/Monopoly%20Deal%20Rules.pdf), but the effect is the same:

> If you have more than 7 cards in your hand at the end of your turn (not including cards on the table) discard extras to the bottom of the draw pile so you only have 7. If you've run out of cards, take 5 at the start of your next turn.

[Scan of those rules](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=instructionbook)
[PDF of those rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/41256/monopoly-deal-rules-pdf)

#### The other way (to the play pile)

[These rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/dad288661c4311ddbd0b0800200c9a66/6CDE82515056900B10F41868CA079DC6.pdf) (branded "Monopoly Millionaire", but they're the only ruleset I can find that gives the alternate play style) say to place them on the play pile (in which case they'd be placed face up like other cards placed there):

> Just before the next player’s turn, check how many cards you have left
> in your hand.
>
> - More than 7? Throw any extras on the play pile

#### Both Ways (monopolydealrules.com)

This unofficial site says that the rule is to discard to the discard pile, but references the official rules that say to discard to the bottom of the draw pile:

[General summary:](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=play)

> At the end of each player’s turn, they cannot have more than 7 cards in their hand. If they do, they need to discard the excess Monopoly cards into the discard pile in the middle.

[Linked rules](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=instructionbook#top):

> If you have more than 7 cards in your hand at the end of your turn (not including cards on the table) discard extras to the bottom of the draw pile so you only have 7.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the card should be laid down to build another deck. Then was the initial deck is exhausted, a player shuffles the new deck and the game continues.

I hope this works.

Thanks.